# Google Map Dialog/Info Window Not Appearing on Touch

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to add infowindows to markers/pushpins on the map. ATM, it is not working.
Current code:
TravelBuddy.java/TabHost

```
package com.jappapps.android.travelbuddy;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

public class TravelBuddy extends TabActivity {

TabHost mTabHost;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Context ctx = this.getApplicationContext();

    //tab 1
    mTabHost = getTabHost();
    TabSpec tabSpec1 = mTabHost.newTabSpec("Maps");
    tabSpec1.setIndicator("Map");
    Intent i1 = new Intent(ctx, MapTabView.class);
    tabSpec1.setContent(i1);
    mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec1);

    //tab2
    mTabHost = getTabHost();
    TabSpec tabSpec2 = mTabHost.newTabSpec("Web");
    tabSpec2.setIndicator("Featured");
    Intent i2 = new Intent(ctx, WebView1.class);
    tabSpec2.setContent(i2);
    mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec2);
    /*
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable =               this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
    Overlays itemizedoverlay = new Overlays(drawable);*/
}
   }
```

MapTabView.java/Map:

```
package com.jappapps.android.travelbuddy;

import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class MapTabView extends MapActivity {

MapController mapController;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    setContentView(R.layout.maptabview);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);    
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
    Overlays1 itemizedoverlay = new Overlays1(drawable);

    GeoPoint un = new GeoPoint((int) (59.911868847598406*1E6), (int) (10.73362112045288*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(un, "Oslo Rådhus", "Oslo Rådhus");
    GeoPoint lc = new GeoPoint((int) (59.913676042809527*1E6), (int) (10.739468336105347*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(lc, "Grand Hotel/Grand Cafe", "Grand Hotel/Grand Cafe");
    GeoPoint pr = new GeoPoint((int) (59.906446671638705*1E6), (int) (10.736163854598999*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem3 = new OverlayItem(pr, "Akershus Festning", "Akershus Festning");
    GeoPoint dtc = new GeoPoint((int) (59.96375425571723*1E6), (int) (10.668411254882812*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem4 = new OverlayItem(dtc, "Holmenkollen Nasjonalanlegg", "Holmenkollen Nasjonalanlegg");
    GeoPoint un1 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.873818*1E6), (int) (2.295023*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem5 = new OverlayItem(un1, "Arc De Triomphe", "Arc De Triomphe");
    GeoPoint lc1 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.858205*1E6), (int) (2.294359*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem6 = new OverlayItem(lc1, "Eiffel Tower", "Eiffel Tower");
    GeoPoint pr1 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.85253054945084*1E6), (int) (2.3359479010105133*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem7 = new OverlayItem(pr1, "Le Golfe De Naples", "Akershus Festning");
    GeoPoint dtc1 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.8701101964186*1E6), (int) (2.30538547039032*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem8 = new OverlayItem(dtc1, "L'Atelier Renault", "L'Atelier Renault");
    GeoPoint dtc2 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.86751841374421*1E6), (int) (2.322430908679962*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem9 = new OverlayItem(dtc2, "Maxims", "Maxims");       
    GeoPoint un2 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.85047705575626*1E6), (int) (2.2914178669452667*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem10 = new OverlayItem(un2, "Hotel Eiffel Capitol", "Hotel Eiffel Capitol");
    GeoPoint lc2 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.837701*1E6), (int) (2.34641*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem11 = new OverlayItem(lc2, "The Five Hotel", "The Five Hotel");
    GeoPoint pr2 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.8484067*1E6), (int) (2.2971547*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem12 = new OverlayItem(pr2, "Hotel Saphir Grenelle", "Hotel Sapfir Grenelle");
    GeoPoint dtc3 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.84850466945429*1E6), (int) (2.3204205930233*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem13 = new OverlayItem(dtc3, "Hotel Vaneau Saint-Germain", "Vaneau Saint-Germain");
    GeoPoint un3 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.8663741*1E6), (int) (2.3084308*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem14 = new OverlayItem(un3, "Hotel San Régis", "Hotel San Régis");
    GeoPoint lc3 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.88319585446909*1E6), (int) (2.2988489270210266*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem15 = new OverlayItem(lc3, "Bacino", "Bacino");
    GeoPoint pr3 = new GeoPoint((int) (51.50056503296835*1E6), (int) (-0.1246422529220581*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem16 = new OverlayItem(pr3, "Big Ben", "Big Ben");
    GeoPoint dtc4 = new GeoPoint((int) (51.49942628765944*1E6), (int) (-0.12577414512634277*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem17 = new OverlayItem(dtc4, "Houses Of Parliament", "Houses Of Parliament");
    GeoPoint dtc5 = new GeoPoint((int) (51.50163696369762*1E6), (int) (-0.1411592960357666*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem18 = new OverlayItem(dtc5, "Buckingham Palace", "Buckingham Palace");        
    GeoPoint un4 = new GeoPoint((int) (51.50558385576479*1E6), (int) (-0.08531838655471802*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem19 = new OverlayItem(un4, "London Dungeon", "London Dungeon");
    GeoPoint lc5 = new GeoPoint((int) (51.41935569771223*1E6), (int) (-0.19598767161369324*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem20 = new OverlayItem(lc5, "Antoinette Hotel Wimbledon", "Antoinette Hotel Wimbledon");
    GeoPoint pr5 = new GeoPoint((int) (51.5120631*1E6), (int) (-0.0790412*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem21 = new OverlayItem(pr5, "The Tower - A Guoman Hotel", "The Tower - A Guoman Hotel");
    GeoPoint dtc6 = new GeoPoint((int) (51.50645199258505*1E6), (int) (-0.07380366325378418*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem22 = new OverlayItem(dtc6, "Water Cafe", "Water Cafe");
    GeoPoint un5 = new GeoPoint((int) (51.50650541584913*1E6), (int) (-0.07335305213928223*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem23 = new OverlayItem(un5, "The Brasserie", "The Brasserie");
    GeoPoint lc6 = new GeoPoint((int) (51.51877441241732*1E6), (int) (-0.1319056749343872*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem24 = new OverlayItem(lc6, "MyHotel Bloomsbury", "MyHotel Bloomsbury");
    GeoPoint pr6 = new GeoPoint((int) (40.4528417284077*1E6), (int) (-3.6893677711486816*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem25 = new OverlayItem(pr6, "Santiago Bernabeu", "Santiago Bernabeu");
    GeoPoint dtc7 = new GeoPoint((int) (40.41366759389503*1E6), (int) (-3.692554235458374*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem26 = new OverlayItem(dtc7, "Prado Museum", "Prado Museum");
    GeoPoint dtc8 = new GeoPoint((int) (40.4163542*1E6), (int) (-3.6949915*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem27 = new OverlayItem(dtc8, "Thyssen Museum", "Thyssen Museum");      
    GeoPoint un6 = new GeoPoint((int) (40.4085453*1E6), (int) (-3.6940541*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem28 = new OverlayItem(un6, "Reina Sofia", "Reina Sofia");
    GeoPoint lc7 = new GeoPoint((int) (40.440325146081875*1E6), (int) (-3.670211434364319*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem29 = new OverlayItem(lc7, "Hotel Silken Puerta America", "Hotel Silken Puerta America");
    GeoPoint pr7 = new GeoPoint((int) (40.41960806285972*1E6), (int) (-3.6996057629585266*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem30 = new OverlayItem(pr7, "Hotel De Las Letras", "Hotel De Las Letras");
    GeoPoint dtc9 = new GeoPoint((int) (40.440325146081875*1E6), (int) (-3.670211434364319*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem31 = new OverlayItem(dtc9, "MAD Resturant", "MAD Resturant");
    GeoPoint un7 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.40314508867334*1E6), (int) (2.1737265586853027*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem32 = new OverlayItem(un7, "Sagrada Familia", "Sagrada Familia");
    GeoPoint lc8 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.41350532776538*1E6), (int) (2.1529877185821533*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem33 = new OverlayItem(lc8, "Park Güell", "Park Güell");
    GeoPoint pr8= new GeoPoint((int) (41.38142144742531*1E6), (int) (2.1210265159606934*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem34 = new OverlayItem(pr8, "Camp Nou", "Camp Nou");
    GeoPoint dtc10 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.4974299*1E6), (int) (2.1574864*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem35 = new OverlayItem(dtc10, "Museum Picasso", "Museum Picasso");
    GeoPoint dtc11 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.3839147*1E6), (int) (2.183351*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem36 = new OverlayItem(dtc11, "Resturant Cal Pep", "Resturant Cal Pep");       
    GeoPoint un8 = new GeoPoint((int) (59.911868847598406*1E6), (int) (10.73362112045288*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem37 = new OverlayItem(un8, "Alkimia Resturant", "Alkimia Resturant");
    GeoPoint lc9 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.3909339796086*1E6), (int) (2.149248719215393*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem38 = new OverlayItem(lc9, "Resturant Vinya Roel", "Resturant Vinya Roel");
    GeoPoint pr9 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.410423580724746*1E6), (int) (2.136486768722534*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem39 = new OverlayItem(pr9, "ABAC Hotel", "ABAC Hotel");
    GeoPoint dtc12 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.3776992*1E6), (int) (2.1390646*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem40 = new OverlayItem(dtc12, "Hotel AC Sants", "Hotel AC Sants");
    GeoPoint un9 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.38435766200757*1E6), (int) (2.178337275981903*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem41 = new OverlayItem(un9, "Hotel H10 Montcada", "Hotel H10 Montcada");
    GeoPoint lc10 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.88996250292627*1E6), (int) (12.49321460723877*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem42 = new OverlayItem(lc10, "Colosseum", "Colosseum");
    GeoPoint pr10 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.90089556707864*1E6), (int) (12.48333603143692*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem43 = new OverlayItem(pr10, "Trevi Fountain", "Trevi Fountain");
    GeoPoint dtc13 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.8933727975499*1E6), (int) (12.483032941818237*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem44 = new OverlayItem(dtc13, "Capitoline Museums", "Capitoline Museums");
    GeoPoint dtc14 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.903061593027836*1E6), (int) (12.45436280965805*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem45 = new OverlayItem(dtc14, "Sistine Chapel", "Sistine Chapel");     
    GeoPoint un10 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.9058324020521341E6), (int) (12.482188045978546*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem46 = new OverlayItem(un10, "Piazza Di Spagna", "Piazza Di Spagna");
    GeoPoint lc11 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.9005422084091*1E6), (int) (12.476523220539093*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem47 = new OverlayItem(lc11, "Gelateria Della Palma", "Gelateria Della Palma");
    GeoPoint pr11 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.8993638*1E6), (int) (12.4727763*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem48 = new OverlayItem(pr11, "Resturant Tre Scalini", "Resturant Tre Scalini");
    GeoPoint dtc15 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.89913673988211*1E6), (int) (12.49245822429657*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem49 = new OverlayItem(dtc15, "Pizzeria Est! Est! Est! Dei Fratelli Ricci", "Pizzeria Est! Est! Est! Dei Fratelli Ricci");
    GeoPoint un11 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.8987143*1E6), (int) (12.4715744*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem50 = new OverlayItem(un11, "Hotel Teatro Pace 33", "Hotel Teatro Pace 33");
    GeoPoint lc12 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.896669109513695*1E6), (int) (12.50568151473999*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem51 = new OverlayItem(lc12, "Radisson Sas Es Hotel Roma", "Radisson Sas Es Hotel Roma");
    GeoPoint pr13 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.895373*1E6), (int) (12.4892684*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem52 = new OverlayItem(pr13, "Casa Il Rosario", "Casa Il Rosario");
    GeoPoint dtc16 = new GeoPoint((int) (43.701068*1E6), (int) (7.2796387*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem53 = new OverlayItem(dtc16, "Resturant Au Petit Gari", "Resturant Au Petit Gari");
    GeoPoint dtc17 = new GeoPoint((int) (43.705593*1E6), (int) (7.2821517*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem54 = new OverlayItem(dtc17, "Hotel Relais Acropolis", "Hotel Relais Acropolis");     
    GeoPoint un12 = new GeoPoint((int) (51.50558385576479*1E6), (int) (-0.08531838655471802*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem55 = new OverlayItem(un12, "Holiday Inn Hotel Resort Port St.Laurent", "Holiday Inn Hotel Resort Port St.Laurent");
    GeoPoint lc13 = new GeoPoint((int) (43.6989919*1E6), (int) (7.2601172*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem56 = new OverlayItem(lc13, "Gounod Hotel", "Gounod Hotel");
    GeoPoint pr14 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.21070419133567*1E6), (int) (16.358535289764404*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem57 = new OverlayItem(pr14, "Vienna City Hall/Rathaus", "Vienna City Hall/Rathaus");
    GeoPoint dtc18 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.20055071992264*1E6), (int) (16.37714982032776*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem58 = new OverlayItem(dtc18, "Imperial Court Theatre", "Imperial Court Theatre");
    GeoPoint un13 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.2169714*1E6), (int) (16.39592*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem59 = new OverlayItem(un13, "Wiener Riesenrad", "Wiener Riesenrad");
    GeoPoint lc14 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.2027121*1E6), (int) (16.3702019*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem60 = new OverlayItem(lc14, "Resturant Korso", "Resturant Korso");
    GeoPoint pr15 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.2096951*1E6), (int) (16.3737617*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem61 = new OverlayItem(pr15, "Pizza Bizi", "Pizza Bizi");
    GeoPoint dtc19 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.2044364*1E6), (int) (16.3813728*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem62 = new OverlayItem(dtc19, "Resturant Steirereck", "Restrant Steirereck");
    GeoPoint dtc20 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.20973540822208*1E6), (int) (16.365820169448853*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem63 = new OverlayItem(dtc20, "Steigenberger Hotel Herrenhof", "Steigenberger Hotel Herrenhof");       
    GeoPoint un14 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.2016895*1E6), (int) (16.37109831*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem64 = new OverlayItem(un14, "The Ring Hotel", "The Ring Hotel");
    GeoPoint lc15 = new GeoPoint((int) (48.2021021*1E6), (int) (16.3721863*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem65 = new OverlayItem(lc15, "Grand Hotel Wien", "Grand Hotel Wien");
    GeoPoint pr16 = new GeoPoint((int) (59.32845018256806*1E6), (int) (18.09195041656494*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem66 = new OverlayItem(pr16, "The Vasa Museum", "The Vasa Museum");
    GeoPoint dtc21 = new GeoPoint((int) (59.32970893771183*1E6), (int) (18.092358112335205*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem67 = new OverlayItem(dtc21, "Junibacken", "Junibacken");
    GeoPoint un15 = new GeoPoint((int) (59.3073348*1E6), (int) (18.0747967*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem68 = new OverlayItem(un15, "Clarion Hotel Stockholm", "Clarion Hotel Stockholm");
    GeoPoint lc16 = new GeoPoint((int) (59.3254337*1E6), (int) (18.0753632*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem69 = new OverlayItem(lc16, "Hotel Reisen", "Hotel Reisen");
    GeoPoint pr17= new GeoPoint((int) (59.3299036*1E6), (int) (18.0715709*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem70 = new OverlayItem(pr17, "Cafe Opera", "Cafe Opera");
    GeoPoint dtc22 = new GeoPoint((int) (41.4974299*1E6), (int) (2.1574864*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem71 = new OverlayItem(dtc22, "Sturehof Resturant", "Sturehof Resturant");
    GeoPoint dtc23 = new GeoPoint((int) (55.692711148828536*1E6), (int) (12.599140405654907*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem72 = new OverlayItem(dtc23, "The Little Mermaid", "The Little Mermaid");     
    GeoPoint un16 = new GeoPoint((int) (55.67800786998909*1E6), (int) (12.572801113128662*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem73 = new OverlayItem(un16, "Strøget", "Strøget");
    GeoPoint lc17 = new GeoPoint((int) (55.6747595*1E6), (int) (12.565412*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem74 = new OverlayItem(lc17, "Copenhagen Tivoli", "Copenhagen Tivoli");
    GeoPoint pr18 = new GeoPoint((int) (55.6779738*1E6), (int) (12.5978009*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem75 = new OverlayItem(pr18, "Resturant Noma", "Resturant Noma");
    GeoPoint dtc24 = new GeoPoint((int) (55.6747595*1E6), (int) (12.565412*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem76 = new OverlayItem(dtc24, "The Paul Resturant", "The Paul Resturant");
    GeoPoint un17 = new GeoPoint((int) (55.678742*1E6), (int) (12.5841987*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem77 = new OverlayItem(un17, "Restaurant Kong Hans Kælder", "Restaurant Kong Hans Kælder");
    GeoPoint lc18 = new GeoPoint((int) (55.66787989681918*1E6), (int) (12.584280967712402*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem78 = new OverlayItem(lc18, "Radisson Blu Scandinavia Hotel Copenhagen", "Radisson Blu Scandinavia Hotel Copenhagen");
    GeoPoint pr19 = new GeoPoint((int) (55.68151324*1E6), (int) (12.5929088*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem79 = new OverlayItem(pr19, "Copenhagen Admiral Hotel", "Copenhagen Admiral Hotel");
    GeoPoint dtc25 = new GeoPoint((int) (55.6786431*1E6), (int) (12.566237*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem80 = new OverlayItem(dtc25, "Hotel Fox", "Hotel Fox");
    GeoPoint dtc26 = new GeoPoint((int) (45.46419413386295*1E6), (int) (9.190621376037598*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem81 = new OverlayItem(dtc26, "Duomo of Milan", "Duomo of Milan");     
    GeoPoint un18 = new GeoPoint((int) (45.46730552025704*1E6), (int) (9.189741611480713*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem82 = new OverlayItem(un18, "La Scala Theatre", "La Scala Theatre");
    GeoPoint lc19 = new GeoPoint((int) (45.469401000526105*1E6), (int) (9.180772304534912*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem83 = new OverlayItem(lc19, "Sforzesco Castle", "Sforzesco Castle");
    GeoPoint pr20 = new GeoPoint((int) (45.4571409*1E6), (int) (9.184143*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem84 = new OverlayItem(pr20, "SHU Café", "SHU Café");
    GeoPoint dtc27 = new GeoPoint((int) (45.4774833*1E6), (int) (9.1879434*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem84b = new OverlayItem(dtc27, "Rangoli Resturant", "Rangoli Resturant");
    GeoPoint un19 = new GeoPoint((int) (45.4728739*1E6), (int) (9.1925647*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem85 = new OverlayItem(un19, "Hotel Cavour", "Hotel Cavour");
    GeoPoint lc20 = new GeoPoint((int) (45.4833898*1E6), (int) (9.203065*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem86 = new OverlayItem(lc20, " Hotel Augustus Milano", " Hotel Augustus Milano");
    GeoPoint pr21 = new GeoPoint((int) (52.521104203431*1E6), (int) (13.409993648529053*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem87 = new OverlayItem(pr21, "Berliner Fernsehturm", "Berliner Fernsehturm");
    GeoPoint dtc28 = new GeoPoint((int) (52.5024116*1E6), (int) (13.3407873*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem88 = new OverlayItem(dtc28, "KaDeWe", "KaDeWe");
    GeoPoint dtc29 = new GeoPoint((int) (52.5024116*1E6), (int) (13.3407873*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem89 = new OverlayItem(dtc29, "Sony Center Berlin", "Sony Center Berlin");     
    GeoPoint un20 = new GeoPoint((int) (52.5167268*1E6), (int) (13.3811334*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem90 = new OverlayItem(un20, "Hotel Adlon Kempinski", "Hotel Adlon Kempinski");
    GeoPoint lc21 = new GeoPoint((int) (47.3790239*1E6), (int) (8.5410038*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem91 = new OverlayItem(lc21, "Swiss National Museum", "Swiss National Museum");
    GeoPoint pr22 = new GeoPoint((int) (47.37522381*1E6), (int) (8.5480097*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem92 = new OverlayItem(pr22, "Zoological Museum Zurich", "Zoological Museum Zurich");
    GeoPoint dtc30 = new GeoPoint((int) (47.3646155*1E6), (int) (8.5341921*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem93 = new OverlayItem(dtc30, "Alden Hotel Splügenschloss", "Alden Hotel Splügenschloss");
    GeoPoint un21 = new GeoPoint((int) (47.3673009*1E6), (int) (8.5393579*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem94 = new OverlayItem(un21, "Baur au Lac Hotel", "Baur au Lac Hotel");
    GeoPoint lc22 = new GeoPoint((int) (47.3724962*1E6), (int) (8.5397697*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem95 = new OverlayItem(lc22, "Widder Hotel", "Widder Hotel");
    GeoPoint pr23 = new GeoPoint((int) (47.3519342*1E6), (int) (8.5611453*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem96 = new OverlayItem(pr23, "Blaue Ente Resturant", "Blaue Ente Resturant");
    GeoPoint dtc31 = new GeoPoint((int) (47.384317*1E6), (int) (8.5301602*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem97 = new OverlayItem(dtc31, "El Parador Resturant", "El Parador Resturant");
    GeoPoint dtc32 = new GeoPoint((int) (50.1154854*1E6), (int) (8.6712932*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem98 = new OverlayItem(dtc32, "Resturant Charlot", "Resturant Chalot");        
    GeoPoint un22 = new GeoPoint((int) (50.113269*1E6), (int) (8.6655786*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem99 = new OverlayItem(un22, "Restaurant Alte Kanzlei", "Restaurant Alte Kanzlei");
    GeoPoint lc23 = new GeoPoint((int) (50.1079716*1E6), (int) (8.6616355*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem100 = new OverlayItem(lc23, "Steigenberger Hotel Metropolitan", "Steigenberger Hotel Metropolitan");
    GeoPoint pr24 = new GeoPoint((int) (50.1079054*1E6), (int) (8.6614363*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem101 = new OverlayItem(pr24, "InterCityHotel Frankfurt", "InterCityHotel Frankfurt");
    GeoPoint dtc33 = new GeoPoint((int) (50.118211*1E6), (int) (8.6267511*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem102 = new OverlayItem(dtc33, "Radisson Blu Frankfurt", "Radisson Blu Frankfurt");
    GeoPoint un23 = new GeoPoint((int) (50.1173658*1E6), (int) (8.6525491*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem103 = new OverlayItem(un23, "Senckenberg Natural History Museum", "Senckenberg Natural History Museum");
    GeoPoint lc24 = new GeoPoint((int) (60.14791385553872*1E6), (int) (24.986085891723633*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem104 = new OverlayItem(lc24, "Suomenlinna Fortress", "Suomenlinna Fortress");
    GeoPoint pr25= new GeoPoint((int) (60.17486121440947*1E6), (int) (24.93196964263916*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem105 = new OverlayItem(pr25, "National Museum of Finland", "National Museum of Finland");
    GeoPoint dtc34 = new GeoPoint((int) (60.17251327443952*1E6), (int) (24.92527484893799*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem106 = new OverlayItem(dtc34, "Temppeliaukio Church", "Temppeliaukio Church");
    GeoPoint dtc35 = new GeoPoint((int) (60.1661015*1E6), (int) (24.9462893*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem107 = new OverlayItem(dtc35, "Resturant Chez Dominique", "Resturant Chez Dominique");        
    GeoPoint un24 = new GeoPoint((int) (60.1667065*1E6), (int) (24.9370801*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem108 = new OverlayItem(un24, "Lappi Resturant", "Lappi Resturant");
    GeoPoint lc25 = new GeoPoint((int) (60.1658221*1E6), (int) (24.9643121*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem109 = new OverlayItem(lc25, "Scandic Grand Marina", "Scandic Grand Marina");
    GeoPoint pr26 = new GeoPoint((int) (60.1620404*1E6), (int) (24.91947054862976*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem110 = new OverlayItem(pr26, "Radisson SAS Royal Hotel Helsinki", "Radisson SAS Royal Hotel Helsinki");
    GeoPoint dtc36 = new GeoPoint((int) (50.0890201*1E6), (int) (14.3953924*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem111 = new OverlayItem(dtc36, "Prague Castle", "Prague Castle");
    GeoPoint un25 = new GeoPoint((int) (50.0791783*1E6), (int) (14.430561*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem112 = new OverlayItem(un25, "Czech National Museum", "Czech National Museum");
    GeoPoint lc26 = new GeoPoint((int) (50.0867185*1E6), (int) (14.4203544*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem113 = new OverlayItem(lc26, "Prague Astronomical Clock", "Prague Astronomical Clock");
    GeoPoint pr27 = new GeoPoint((int) (50.0847624*1E6), (int) (14.4181824*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem114 = new OverlayItem(pr27, "Flambee Restaurant", "Flambee Restaurant");
    GeoPoint dtc37 = new GeoPoint((int) (50.0870934*1E6), (int) (14.4082526*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem115 = new OverlayItem(dtc37, "Kampa Park Restaurant", "Kampa Park Restaurant");
    GeoPoint dtc38 = new GeoPoint((int) (50.0840176*1E6), (int) (14.4251538*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem116 = new OverlayItem(dtc38, "Hotel Ambassador-Zlatá Husa", "Hotel Ambassador-Zlatá Husa");      
    GeoPoint un26 = new GeoPoint((int) (50.0819621*1E6), (int) (50.0819621*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem117 = new OverlayItem(un26, "Hotel Galileo", "Hotel Galileo");


    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem3);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem4);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem5);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem6);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem7);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem8);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem9);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem10);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem11);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem12);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem13);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem14);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem15);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem16);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem17);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem18);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem19);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem20);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem21);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem22);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem23);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem24);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem25);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem26);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem27);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem28);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem29);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem30);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem31);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem32);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem33);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem34);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem35);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem36);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem37);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem38);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem39);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem40);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem41);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem42);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem43);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem44);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem45);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem46);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem47);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem48);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem49);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem50);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem51);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem52);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem53);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem54);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem55);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem56);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem57);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem58);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem59);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem60);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem61);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem62);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem63);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem64);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem65);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem66);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem67);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem68);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem69);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem70);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem71);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem72);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem73);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem74);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem75);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem76);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem77);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem78);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem79);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem80);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem81);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem82);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem83);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem84);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem84b);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem85);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem86);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem87);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem88);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem89);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem90);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem91);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem92);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem93);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem94);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem95);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem96);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem97);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem98);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem99);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem100);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem101);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem102);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem103);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem104);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem105);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem106);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem107);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem108);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem109);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem110);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem111);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem112);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem113);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem114);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem115);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem116);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Android Google Maps API does not provide info windows for markers/pushpins. You have to write that by yourself. However, there is 3rd party open source 'library' which implements it and it is available here:

http://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

Comment: Hmm, the mapview tutorial from Google says it should work, but anyway, this seems like a very, very good alternative! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line to your code:

```
mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```