# Bubble pop up box

Tags: android, google-maps

Google map, it allows us to pin-point any location we want. After pin-pointing, there will be this "Bubble" pop up box at the top of the push-pin. May i know how to do the pop up window box? Any codes to show? I am using alert dialog box now, but i want it to be "Bubble" pop up window instead.

```
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();

        mapOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

        // obtain gps location
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(
        // LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

            k = new GeoPoint((int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                    (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1E6));
            mc.animateTo(k);
            mc.setZoom(18);

            // Add a location marker
            MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
            List<Overlay> listofOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            listofOverlays.clear();
            listofOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

            // invalidate() method forces the MapView to be redrawn
            mapView.invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {

        @Override
        public boolean onTap(final GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            k = p;
            mc = mapView.getController();
            mc.animateTo(p);

            mapView.invalidate();

            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),
                    Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                        p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6, p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);
                String add = "";
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < addresses.get(0)
                            .getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                        add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                    txtAddress.setText("Address: " + add);
                }
@Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
                long when) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
            if (k != null) {
                // ---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
                Point screenPts = new Point();
                mapView.getProjection().toPixels(k, screenPts);

                // ---add the marker---
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.passenger);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 50, null);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on a mapping application where I also needed to display 'Bubble' popups and the following blog posts helped me quite a bit.

[This first post](http://www.actionshrimp.com/2011/05/speech-bubble-popups-containing-a-view-for-android-mapview/) shows how to use a 9-patch image embedded in a view to produce a popup. The code is ok but does leave a number of questions unanswered, some commenters have requested some additional source code for clarification.

[This post from the Android Developers blog](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) explains what a 9 patch image is an how to create one.

Using these two posts I was able to pull some code together which works well so hopefully you will be able to manipulate it to fit your needs too.

Comment: Just an update to this - the first post is on my own blog, and I've now added a link to the full source code on there in case that helps anyone at any point.

Comment: Thanks for the update - and the source, I found the post really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for the [InfoWindow](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows). By the way, in newer versions of the API, they do not have rounded corners (they look more like boxes and less like bubbles). You can restore the old ones by requesting a previous version of the API in the javascript URL that loads the maps API.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean. Do you have any codes example ? How am i suppose to put the codes in?

Comment: Did you read the link I sent you? It has code examples. You can also look at the InfoWindow API reference here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindow

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't provide an API to do this, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349095/google-map-dialog-info-window-not-appearing-on-touch). Victor's answer gives a link to open source code which fits the bill.