# gmap info window on android

Tags: android, google-maps, mono

i'm trying to use gmap on android (trying to develop it using mono for android by the way), but I don't think I see any mention of info window (like we use to see it in gmap web version) in any of the gmap documentation.. so is there any such thing as info window for gmap for android?

just in case, here's the sample code to generate info window on marker for web based gmap api

```
GEvent.addListener(markers[i], "click", function(info) {
          this.openInfoWindowHtml(info);                      
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that gmaps for android has no support for "bubble windows" but take a look here: [Google Map Dialog/Info Window Not Appearing on Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349095/google-map-dialog-info-window-not-appearing-on-touch)